# Proof: Show that if $a \in\mathbb Z$ then $a^2 \not\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and $a^2\not\equiv 3 \pmod 4.$

Tags: logic

I am having trouble formulating this proof.

My best guess would be by contradiction.

Proof by contradiction:
Assume that a is an integer. Then a^2≡2(mod4) or a^2≡3(mod4).
We can then look at this by cases:

Case 1)
a^2≡2(mod4) can be written as 4|(a^2-2).
From here, would you just separate into remainders 1,2, and 3, and find the contradiction for each? Then repeat for case 2 where 4|(a^2-3)?

I'm a little lost as to where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you intuitively understand why this is true? is it just the formalism you are struggling with?

Comment: What do you know about modular arithmetic?  Please **edit the question** to let us know what you've tried and where you're stuck, as well as telling us what tools are available to you.

Comment: Very easy to brute force through all 4 cases. i.e. $a = 0, 1, 2, 3$

Comment: From $a^2\equiv 2\pmod 4$, deduce that $a^2$ is even, and so $a$ is even, then something contradicts. But if you go on this route, maybe it's easier to start by considering $a$ with different remainders mod 4 (or even mod 2).

Answer (score 1):

There are exactly 4 possibilities, for any $a$. (i) If $a\equiv  0 \pmod 4,$ then $a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ (ii) If $a\equiv  1 \pmod 4,$ then $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ (iii)If $a\equiv  2 \pmod 4,$ then $a^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ (iv)If $a\equiv  3 \pmod 4,$ then $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

Comment: I would say that $a \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow a^2 \equiv 9 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, just to make it clear why that last modular equality holds.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to look at it.  If $a$ is even, then $a=2k, k \in \Bbb Z$ so $a^2=4k^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

If $a$ is odd, then $a=2k+1, k \in \Bbb Z$, so $a^2=4k^2+4k+1 = 4(k^2+k)+1 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.